# Java best way to make two teams?

Tags: java, interface

What would be the best way to make two teams using java?
Using an interface named Team with some values? How would I add strings to the teams then? Would I have to make a new Manager (addTeamMember) for each team? 
Would it be better to just make two classes?
(I want to be able to expand it easily so the last method is my last resort)
Thanks.

Comment: Why an interface?

Comment: What is a `Team`? What does it do? What does it consist of? What strings are you trying to add? What does a manager do? How many managers can a `Team` have? Are there key differences between different `Team`s? There's no way we can know these things to help you. Just make a class.

Comment: Create a Team class with proper team attributes. Then create as many objects with whatever values you like

Comment: Kayman I was looking on the java page and interface looked like this to me interface Engine { int power = x } and then class X implements Engine { power = y }

Comment: Zircon a Team would be an interface with a String name, String color, and an ArrayList<String> members. A manager would be used to add members (strings) to the teams. Not many differences except name color and members.

Comment: Rafiduzzaman Sonnet, how wiuld I add members (strings) to the objects? Sorry but I havent learned much about this.

Comment: Make it a class instead of an interface.

Comment: Thank you Rafiduzzman Sonnet, I now see what you mean, this was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new class you could use the `Set` interface.

```
Set<String> team1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> team2 = new HashSet<>();
```

You find the documentation with all the methods it offers you [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

(**add**(String name), **contains**(String name), **remove**(String name) ... you'll also have an iterator)

You could easly add members and you don't have to worry about duplicates.

In the end a team is just a group (a Set) of people

Answer (score 0):

Make a class with a constructor to set the variables you need (name, color, members), make a variable in your main class that is something like

```
  Team red = new Team("red","RED",null);
   red.addMember("Lucas");
   red.getMembers();
```

Thanks to Rafiduzzman Sonet for making me realise.